# concave mirror with weird reflection

Tags: mirror

I made a simulation of a concave mirror for my physics class. A strange circle appears in the center of the mirror, and going outwards "lines" appers. Does it really happen this way in real life? Is it an error or is it misconfigured?
[image]

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Cycles isn't really good choice for physics demonstrations, you might want to install another render engine if you need correct caustics. That said, try to enter Edit mode for the ball and recalculate normals outside for face which corresponds to weird reflection. You could also include a screenshot of mesh in solid mode.

Comment: I had already tried to flip normals and different types of spheres.
same result.

Comment: I fixed it!
to solve this problem you have to select the mirror (object) go to object properties -> cycles settings -> disable "Glossy".